# TLD handling between browser and ISP is opaque, relying on 127.0.0.1

Tags: networking, macos, dns

Observing different behaviours between OSes relating to TLDs.
Specifically, MacOS 10.9.5 and 10.13.6.
*both are connecting via the same wi-fi hotspot, with identical settings under Apple's network configurations tab, inlcuding the same DNS server.*

a TLD `.dev` on a ping or search with different OSes, but the same ISP connection, will return different results:

- 10.9.5  ping returns 127.0.0.1. A browser cannot connect to the domain with that TLD.
- 10.13.6 ping returns the proper ip address of the domain.  The browser connects to the domain.
- Using a VPN, on 10.9.5, the browser connects to the domain but the ping **remains** pointing to 127.0.0.1

Moving to another TLD  `.tv`:

- 10.9.5  ping returns 127.0.0.1. A browser cannot connect to the domain with that TLD.
- 10.13.6 ping returns 127.0.0.1. A browser cannot connect to the domain with that TLD.
- Using a VPN, on 10.9.5, the browser connects to the domain

Given the ISP connection is the same, I conclude that multiple items are at play here:
a) the OS seems to have lists of TLDs that are naturally dated and missing some, thus lookups are *not* effected & the browser does not connect.  One questions whether this is even pertinent... **can these be updated somehow - even for legacy OSes?**
b) the mechanics of the VPN are different from the ISP - why would the ping still return 127.0.0.1 but the VPN ignores that and routes anyways?

Thus a second question becomes, after consideration of updating the lists of TLDs, is there another way that any TLD can be pinged/lookedup by the ISP (possibly ignoring the TLD listing) ?

**Update**

Given the possible length of items to check, I examined the files sequentially.  Then worked backwards.

Interestingly, `dscacheutil -q host -a name nbc.tv`  points to an AWS server in Germany (CDN I presume).  However, `onhockey.tv` and `google.dev` point to 127.0.0.1, as do the pings. `/etc/resolver.conf`  has a single entry `nameserver 192.168.43.1` which happens to be the one defined via the OS's Network DNS servers interface.

```
host nbc.tv 192.168.43.1
```

resolves to the AWS server `3.64.163.50`
However, as per the `dscacheutil` command, querying the host for the other tv domain and the dev domain returns

```
has address 127.0.0.1
Using domain server:
Name: 192.168.43.1
Address: 192.168.43.1#53
Aliases:
```

`/etc/resolver` does have two files `dev` and `test` put there `generated by Pow`  which serves items locally

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
port 20560
```

Those are not needed anymore.  Although `pow` was uninstalled a long time ago in favour of using `ngrok` services, it was curious these stragglers remained.  Once removed, that resolved the issue with `.dev` domains.  But not the `onhockey.tv` domain.

Thus, this was a multi-pronged issue.

```
dscl /Search -read /Computers/onhockey.tv
> DS Error: -14136 (eDSRecordNotFound)
```

thus remains the `/etc/hosts` file, as a culprit.  There were that were placed there consciously, others not.  Removing the latter still did not allow to resolve the `onhockey.tv` domain.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of macOS can resolve addresses in the new TLDs just fine; something else has to be causing this problem. I've thought a bit about what might be causing this problem, and I'll give some troubleshooting suggestions below.

macOS' resolver doesn't treat different TLDs differently (except .local, which is reserved for Bonjour/mDNS local names); it just sends queries off to the DNS server and lets that figure it out. Here's an example of pinging .tv and .dev domains from a 10.5.8 system I happen to have running:

```
Leopard-MacBook:~ gordon$ ping -c1 nbc.tv
PING nbc.tv (52.58.78.16): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 52.58.78.16: icmp_seq=0 ttl=29 time=169.152 ms

--- nbc.tv ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 169.152/169.152/169.152/0.000 ms

Leopard-MacBook:~ gordon$ ping -c1 google.dev
PING google.dev (216.239.32.27): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 216.239.32.27: icmp_seq=0 ttl=58 time=14.625 ms

--- google.dev ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 14.625/14.625/14.625/0.000 ms
```

Also, trying to use a TLD that can't be looked up (because it doesn't exist) doesn't give 127.0.0.1, it gives a lookup failure:

```
Leopard-MacBook:~ gordon$ ping -c1 google.wibble
ping: cannot resolve google.wibble: Unknown host
```

So the 127.0.0.1 you're getting has to be coming from *somewhere*; the OS's resolver isn't just making it up out of thin air. The question is, where is it coming from?

The first place I'd check is the /etc/hosts file. Entries there override DNS, so anything relevant there may need to be removed. It's also possible (but rare) to create entries in the local "directory" domain; check with e.g. `dscl /Search -read /Computers/whatever.tv`.

Next, check whether you have a /etc/resolver directory; files in there can override the regular DNS config on a per-domain basis (including per-TLD).

Next, do you have multiple DNS servers configured? macOS' resolver does a weird round-robin/DNS-server-lottery system to choose between multiple servers, and if they give different answers, you'll get inconsistent results. Check the servers listed in /etc/resolv.conf with `host`. If you have any IPv6 servers, check them too:

```
Leopard-MacBook:~ gordon$ host nbc.tv 192.168.1.1
Using domain server:
Name: 192.168.1.1
Address: 192.168.1.1#53
Aliases: 

nbc.tv has address 52.58.78.16
nbc.tv has IPv6 address 2a05:d014:9da:8c10:306e:3e07:a16f:a552

Leopard-MacBook:~ gordon$ host nbc.tv 2001:558:feed::1
Using domain server:
Name: 2001:558:feed::1
Address: 2001:558:feed::1#53
Aliases: 

nbc.tv has address 52.58.78.16
nbc.tv has IPv6 address 2a05:d014:9da:8c10:306e:3e07:a16f:a552
```

Compare this with what you get from the system resolver with the `dscacheutil` command:

```
Leopard-MacBook:~ gordon$ dscacheutil -q host -a name nbc.tv
name: nbc.tv
ipv6_address: 2a05:d014:9da:8c10:306e:3e07:a16f:a552

name: nbc.tv
ip_address: 52.58.78.16
```

`dscacheutil` is better than `ping` at showing what the system resolver sees in a couple of ways: it shows IPv6 addresses as well as IPv4 (though there is a `ping6` command), and if there's more than one address available, `ping` will only show one of them.

Speaking of IPv6, that's another possible source of inconsistency: Apple has been switching various parts of the OS to prefer IPv6 over IPv4, so it's possible you have a setup where the newer OS is working because your IPv6 is working and the newer OS is trying that first. So it's important to check *both* (note that the example domains nbc.tv and google.dev have both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, so they're subject to this sort of inconsistency).

Oh, and one more possible source of inconsistency occurs to me: does the VPN config include a web proxy? If so, that might explain why it's working over that (if the browser can reach the proxy, and *that* can resolve and reach the actual web servers).

Comment: Very late follow-up.  I appreciate and have garnered much learning from the post.  Given the length, I presumed an update to the post would be preferable.